# QTreeWidgetItem setting not selectable clears the selection

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have a `QTreeWidget` and I want certain rows to be non select-able, which can be achieved by `QTreeWidgetItem::setFlags(treeWidgetItem->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsSelectable).`

The problem is that I have an existing row that is already selected and later I click on the non select-able row, `selectedItems()` returns an empty list. I want the selected row to keep its selection if the user tries to select a non select-able row.

Should I keep track of the selection and handle this scenario in the code, or this can be achieved somehow else. I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Thank you.

Comment: I have connected to selectionChanged() signal, and that’s where I call it. And at that time I get an empty list. So effectively the newly clicked item was not selected, however the old one was cleared of selection. And it’s not just selectedItems() that is telling me that, I can visually see the selection being cleared...

Comment: Here's when you can find a snippet I just made:
https://github.com/aalimian/TreeWidgetSamples

Comment: I have made the top row non select-able. And I am not able to select it. So that works. But the moment I click on it the selection of the child row disappears.

Comment: Oh and let's not focus on multi-selection now. I have set it up as single selection.

Comment: I don't in this snippet of code. But does it matter? We can clearly see that the selection is getting cleared. I can quickly add it if you like.

Comment: @scopchanov, just added it...

Comment: @scopchanov, please feel free to push to the repo...

Comment: @scopchanov, the solution would be to keep track of the selected items and then when the selection has changed and the selected items list is empty, revert back to the previous selection. I just don't want to do it...

Comment: Just checked it. The problem with that solution is that I wouldn't want the parent node to expand/collapse when I click on it... I guess that can be changed to happen only in the case of double-click...

Comment: void MyTreeWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    QTreeWidgetItem *item = itemAt(event->pos());

    if (item->flags() & Qt::ItemIsSelectable) {
        QTreeWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
    } else if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick) {
        if (item->childCount()) {
            item->setExpanded(!item->isExpanded());
        }
    }
}

Comment: Could you please modify your answer a little bit and add the above snippet of code so I can mark it as the solution? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I did. It works.

Comment: Great! Then I will update my answer and you add those details to your question, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cause

Calling `QTreeView::mousePressEvent(event)` clears the selection when clicked on a non-selectable item if the [selection mode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum) is set to `QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection`.

## Solution

My solution would be to either:

- Set the [selection mode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum) to `QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection`,

or (in case this is not desired):

- Reimplement the mouse events in a subclass of *QTreeWidget* in order to bypass the default behavior.

**Note:** In either case, use the `QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged` signal to get the list of the selected items.

## Example

Here is an example re-implementation of the mouse events in *MyTreeWidget* preventing the selection of being cleared by clicking a non-selectable item. The top item is expanded/collapsed on a double click:

```
void MyTreeWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (indexAt(event->pos())->flags() & Qt::ItemIsSelectable)
        QTreeWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void MyTreeWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QTreeWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(event);

    QTreeWidgetItem *item = itemAt(event->pos());

    if (item && item->childCount())
        item->setExpanded(!item->isExpanded());
}
```

The modified in the described manner version of the provided example is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-TreeWidgetSamples).

## Improvements

Special thanks to @eyllanesc for making this example more waterproof by:

- adding a check if `item` is not `NULL`
- replacing `itemAt` with `indexAt`

Comment: The bad thing about this solution is that the http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#itemClicked and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#itemPressed signal are eliminated for those items. :)

Comment: @eyllanesc, yes, this is the trade-off. I susspect that the drag won't work as well.

Comment: @scopchanov change `if(item->childCount())` to `if(item->childCount() && item)`

Comment: @scopchanov change `if (itemAt(event->pos())->flags() & Qt::ItemIsSelectable)` to `if(indexAt(event->pos())->flags() & Qt::ItemIsSelectable)`, `itemAt()` can return a null pointer and then crashhh XD.

Comment: We're several years later but I have another suggestion to improve this. With this implementation double clicking a disclosure arrow causes it to expand or contract the item an extra time erroneously. I recommend checking to see if the click falls within the disclosure item and then not changing its expanded state in that case. See: https://pastebin.com/y2MYbUX6